# SessionMap does not save the objects JSF

Tags: java, session, jsf, jsf-2

In my application the objects put into `sessionMap` doesn't stored. I can access it in the same object where I have done the put operation, but when I want to do it from another bean, the object doesn't exist. I put the objects into the session in the following way:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put( "myKey", myObject );
```

This is the first time that happens. In another apps I can access the objects stored in the sessionMap.

Best Regards

DrakoRod

Comment: Please add the code where you try to get the object from the sessionMap

Comment: @JasperdeVries yes I use Spring to CDI

Comment: @JasperdeVries But is another way to implement session? or is some kind of solution? Thanks!

Comment: @TheBitman FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); myObject = (MyObject) context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("myKey");

Comment: log the sessionID in your methods handle the get/put into the sessionMap. It should be the same there. If not, your session recreated. Do you access the page from the same browser? Does not throw a `javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException`?

Comment: @TheBitman I logged session id and now I see something rare, when a click menu or enter in url, the session id changes so I think in some part of app the session is recreated right?

Comment: yes, but it is strange. dont you call HttpSession.invalidate?

Comment: Maybe the browser is set up to not keep cookies?

Comment: @TheBitman I reviewed the code and I call HttpSession.invalidate only in the Logout functionv but not in another part.

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov I don't think so because I have other project with the same composition (libraries, xml etc) and the session is going well the only change to this project is a template.

Comment: @TheBitman Sorry for my english the correct comment is "when I do clicked menu or I enter through in a url the session id changes "

Comment: Does the request/response contain the session ID? `...getSession().get("JSESSIONID");`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, finally I resolved the problem, really a don't saw exactly what's was. I explain what I did.

First. My project was in a normal template with this frameworks: JSF 2, primefaces, Spring, Hibernate and log4j. So, all was going well. I added a new template to project and happened the problem with session.

But I just copy/paste code in menu, so I decided write tag by menu's tag and vuala! everything worked.

How I say, I don't saw what's was the problem, but I solved it.